Cannot index models from Django to Elasticsearch
I have a Django project where we're going to use Elasticsearch for a full-text search. I have a task to connect it with the existing Django project. The first thing I found django-elasticsearch-dsl package. I did everything like in tutorial and all worked fine, but the idea was in using elasticsearch-dsl. I don't understand how to create indexes right now. If in django-elasticsearch-dsl the only thing I need is to run python3 manage.py search_index --rebuild inside Django container, but here I have no idea. I store all code in documents.py.
documents.py
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections
from elasticsearch_dsl import Document, Text

connections.create_connection(hosts=['http://elasticsearch:9200'])

class FilmWorkDocument(Document):
    title = Text()
    description = Text()

    class Index:
        name = 'film'
    
FilmWorkDocument.init()

first = FilmWorkDocument(title='Example1', description='Example description')
first.meta.id = 47
first.save()


docker-compose.yml
elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.13.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms200m -Xmx200m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

Sending a request http://localhost:9200 shows that everything is ok.
{
  "name" : "eeb958274241",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "wUQjIKoLTNGKtFH7A1tzSw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.13.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "09df99393193b2c53d92899662a8b8b3c55b45cd",
    "build_date" : "2024-03-22T03:35:46.757803203Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.10.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

But after sending a request http://localhost:9200/film/ it shows that index doesn't exist.
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [film]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"film","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"film"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [film]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"film","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"film"},"status":404}

So, the question are:

How to create and populate index (especially if there are a lot of data in the database and I'm going to index all with bulks)?
Is it a good approach to use elasticsearch-dsl instead of django-elasticsearch-dsl in Django project?

